# How to view the comments and upvotes of comments?

Tags: support, comments, comment-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I view a list of my “great comments”, perhaps in my profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130906/can-i-view-a-list-of-my-great-comments-perhaps-in-my-profile)
>   [Am I really a pundit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133882/am-i-really-a-pundit)
>   [How can I see comments that I’ve upvoted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148008/how-can-i-see-comments-that-ive-upvoted)

Some times we add some comments in questions or answers, how can one view his comments and votes if any user up voted the comments like?

Comment: why down vote ???

Comment: I don't know why but you have [Analytical](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/163/analytical?userid=195216) badge on Meta. So you should know [Voting is different on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: The downvoes here are because you could easily find the answers to your questions by searching Meta. You also didn't tag properly.

Answer (score 7):

The quickest way to see upvotes on comments is to use the old API call (there is a newer version of the API, so the older version may eventually be deprecated).

For example:

```
http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/<your user ID number from your profile>/comments?sort=votes&min=1
```

will display all of your comments which have a score of 1 or higher (change `min` for your specific query).  The result comes back as JSON, which Chrome can display directly, but for IE/FF you used to need a plugin.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Clarified, thanks!

Comment: @AndroSelva What is the exact url that you are using?

Comment: sorry, its working now though I don't get it. It shows only 8 comments that are with 5 or above 5 votes. But I have got my pundit badge. How is it possible?

Comment: Is there any updated API in 2.X which does this task?

Comment: @SwapnilS [Yes](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments-on-users)

Comment: @SwapnilS Use the SEDE with the following query: `DECLARE @UserId int = ##UserId##

SELECT   *, Id as [Comment Link]
FROM     Comments
WHERE    Score >= 5 and UserId = @UserId
ORDER BY Score DESC`

Answer (score 4):

> how can one view his comments?

Go to one's profile --> Activity tab --> Filter comments

e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1410342/shah?tab=activity&sort=comments

> how can one view his votes if any user up voted the comments like?

As I know we can not see where we voted comment.

Comment: what about if some one up voted my comment ???

Comment: Correct there's no way currently to see comments you have upvoted yourself, as jonsca said there's an old API that still works showing your own comments that got upvotes @Farid for your case it's [this](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/1410342/comments?sort=votes&min=1)