# How to find the number of comment votes remaining today?

Tags: support, rate-limiting, comment-voting

How can I find the number of comment votes that I voted today?

Additional question: Is there any way to find out the total number of comment votes of mine for all time?

Comment: You can start feature request asking to add "comments" filter to the "votes" tab in user profile. Other than that, as the answer says what you ask is currently not possible/available.

Comment: Also, [another reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148029/187824) why is this not implemented (see second paragraph)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At present there is no way to find out how many comments we voted today or total number of comment votes we have casted. The only thing we can know is when we reach daily 30 upvotes on comments limit.

IMO this is not implemented because commenting is not our primary goal. Our primary goal is Q&A. Comments are used specially for clarification on question or answer.