# List all comments upvoted by me

Tags: support, comments, data-explorer

I can see all my upvotes in the "votes" tab of my user page. For example,
https://stackoverflow.com/users/139150/shantanuo?tab=votes

This includes the questions, answers and comments. Is there a way to list all comments those I have upvoted?

Comment: I seem to remember seeing a similar request. I shall dig in the archives. Perhaps you should tag the post "feature request"?

Comment: @NathanTuggy I don't think the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148029/223820) to the question you listed above is that relevant to the OP here. The OP here would like to see the  *comments* NOT questions or answers they have upvoted. Actually, that answer *“While you can see the votes you casted on posts (questions and answers), which could be deleted or not but they are originally meant to stay. You can find them like this*”) is a bit misleading.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: The answer there says "what you want to do can't be done. Here's what you *can* do." And, in fact, what this asker wants to do, which is exactly the same, still can't be done.

Comment: @NathanTuggy according to this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130908/223820), upvoted 22 times, the OP can use a SEDE query. If this is no longer true then someone should post an up-to-date answer

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Unfortunately, as I suspected from the question title but did not previously confirm, that question (and that answer) is not relevant. It is asking for *my* comments that *lots of others* upvoted. Interesting, but wholly unrelated to this question, which is asking for *others'* comments that *I* upvoted.

Comment: @NathanTuggy if a SEDE query is possible for comments that have been the most upvoted than surely it means a similar SEDE inquiry could be made for a comment(s) that a user recently, or not, upvoted but no longer remembers where.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Unfortunately, no, not at all. Users' private votes are not stored in SEDE. Comment scores certainly are, but they are denormalized: the actual backing votes that sum to those scores are not visible at all. So it's impossible to, for example, look at the voting breakdown of a comment over time. (If you record a comment's score at various intervals in your own database, you could reconstruct this, but SEDE does not do this.) For similar reasons, SEDE is completely useless in finding posts that you up- or down-voted.

Comment: @NathanTuggy then perhaps the older question, whose link you posted, needs to be updated. You could probably copy and paste your comments and turn it into an answer. I'd be happy to upvote it and delete my vote to close here or hope more users select your suggestion.